# How to handle all Zone Offset in one DateTimeFormater Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I need to create a `DateTimeFormatter` for the following valid dates.

```
  String date1 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28";
  String date2 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777";
  String date3 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777Z";
  String date4 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777UTC";
  String date5 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777-05";
  String date6 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777+05";
  String date7 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777+05:30";
  String date8 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777-05:30";
  String date9 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777+0530";
  String date10 = "2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777-0530";
```

I have tried the following date time formatter, but this fails for last two dates (`date9`, `date10`).

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
                        .optionalStart().appendZoneId().optionalEnd()
                        .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH", "+00").optionalEnd()
                        .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:mm", "+00:00").optionalEnd()
                        .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHmm", "+0000").optionalEnd().toFormatter();
```

All dates from `date1` to `date8` work fine but I get a `DateTimeParseException` when trying to parse last two dates:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-06-20T17:25:28.477777+0530' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 29

For parsing the date I am using following.

```
LocalDateTime.parse(date1, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
```

Valid Pattern for Offset From `OffsetIdPrinterParser`:

```
static final class OffsetIdPrinterParser implements DateTimePrinterParser {
        static final String[] PATTERNS = new String[] {
            "+HH", "+HHmm", "+HH:mm", "+HHMM", "+HH:MM", "+HHMMss", "+HH:MM:ss", "+HHMMSS", "+HH:MM:SS",
        };  // order used in pattern builder
```

I am not able to understand while I am using valid ZoneOffset patterns, why my last two dates fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative is to use optional sections, delimited by `[]`, and the respective [offset patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) (`VV` and `x`):

```
DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
                         // pattern with optional sections: fraction of seconds and offsets
                         .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSS][VV][x][xx][xxx]");
```

Each pair of `[]` is equivalent to one `optionalStart` and `optionalEnd` section. Note that I also had to include the uppercase `S` (fraction of second) as optional, to parse the case where this field is not present.

The other patterns (`VV` and `x`) correspond to the various offsets you need. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-):

```
Pattern  Count  Equivalent builder methods
-------  -----  --------------------------
  VV      2      appendZoneId()
  x       1      appendOffset("+HHmm","+00")
  xx      2      appendOffset("+HHMM","+0000")
  xxx     3      appendOffset("+HH:MM","+00:00")
```

This works for all your input dates.

---

The only difference is that `[.SSSSSS]` accepts **exactly** 6 digits in the **fraction-of-seconds** field (or zero digits, as it's an optional section), while `appendFraction` accepts **any quantity** from 0 to 6 digits. To get exactly this same behaviour, you must use the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```java
DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    // fraction of seconds, from 0 to 6 digits
    .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
    // optional offset patterns
    .appendPattern("[VV][x][xx][xxx]")
    .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply reverse the order of your optional sections:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        .appendFraction(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND, 0, 6, true)
        .optionalStart().appendZoneId().optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHmm", "+0000").optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:mm", "+00:00").optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH", "+00").optionalEnd()
        .toFormatter();
```

This parses all your 10 sample date-time strings.

I am not quite sure why it works. I suppose that it is now trying `+HHmm` before `+HH`, which makes sure it gets alle four digits when there are four, instead of leaving the last two unparsed.

Comment: @Eugene But still we need to find that why Java do this.

Comment: There’s a bit of logic in the order making a difference. Regex are not directly comparable, still `"cats".replaceFirst("cat|cats", "bird")` yields `birds` while the opposite order, `"cats".replaceFirst("cats|cat", "bird")`, just yields `bird`. The date-time formatter doesn’t even give us an OR as in the regex, just a sequence of sections that each are optional, so I gather there’s no alternative to trying them in order.