# How to parse datetime with an offset

Tags: java, android, datetime, kotlin

Date time strings like "2018-04-01 10:00:00" can be used to create Date objects with this Kotlin code:

```
val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val d : Date = format.parse("2018-04-01 10:00:00")   // works fine
```

But how to parse date time strings with offsets like these:

```
2018-04-01 10:00:00+02       // GMT + 2 hours
2018-04-01 10:00:00+02:30    // GMT + 2 hours, 30 minutes
2018-04-01 10:00:00+0230     // GMT + 2 hours, 30 minutes
```

Java 8: Instant is not an option.

edit:

I've tried the suggestion and used 'x', 'X', 'z' and 'Z', 'XXX' with and without leading space. Compiles fine. The x-versions crashes when SimpleDateFormat is instantiated - seems unsupported in the used android api level:

```
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'
var formatter3 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX")

// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'x'
var formatter4 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssx")

// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'x'
var formatter5 = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss x")
```

The z-versions:

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")
or
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssz")
val date = formatter.parse("2018-04-24 17:33:02+02")
```

seems to work.

@Andreas: Date Time parsing is a pain in the ass. Instead of downvoting the question, **a simple line of code** would have been more helpful

Comment: A simple **web search** for the title of your question would have given you many answers: [`java how to parse datetime with an offset`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+how+to+parse+datetime+with+an+offset) --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: Use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX");`

Comment: What do you mean, “Java 8: Instant is not an option.”? What you need is an `OffsetDateTime` from the same API, `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It works nicely on older and newer Android devices. For the older ones add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project and import the classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

Comment: Though not an exact duplicate I think you can find a good answer [here: How to handle all Zone Offset in one DateTimeFormater Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44717044/how-to-handle-all-zone-offset-in-one-datetimeformater-java-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time zones can be parsed with `Z` (RFC 822) or `X` (ISO 8601), see https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat